# Overwrite all class methods with dummy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which has its own methods, for example:

```
class Original():
    def __init__(self, dummy=False):
        self.dummy = dummy

    def funcA(self):
        print('funcA')
```

And I want that, in case the variable `dummy` is true, all the custom made functions from class Original (e.g., funcA) become dummy (i.e., don't do nothing and return nothing).
I have managed to do a dummy class like this:

```
class Dummy(object):
    def dummy(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, _):
        return self.dummy

a = Dummy()
a.asd()  # returns nothing
```

However, I can't manage to make a class in which the writen functions work in case the variable `dummy` is False, and they don't if the variable is True.

Any help please?

Comment: You will need to override `__getattribute__` (not `__getattr__`) in your original class.

Comment: Using ```__getattribute__``` I get an infinite recursive loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out based on Alex Hall's comment. Hope this helps anyone out there:

```
class Dummy(object):
    def __init__(self, isDummy):
        self.isDummy = isDummy

    def dummy(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item in ['isDummy', 'dummy'] or self.isDummy is False:
            attr = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
            return attr
        else:
            return self.dummy

    def funcA(self):
        print('funcA')

print('Dummy:')
dummy = Dummy(isDummy=True)
dummy.funcA()  # returns nothing

print('---')
print('nonDummy:')
nonDummy = Dummy(isDummy=False)
nonDummy.funcA()  # prints 'funcA'
```

Comment: Well done! This is the correct solution, I'm glad I could guide you to finding it yourself. Just be aware that it won't work for any `__magic__` methods.